# How does one, from a list of possible property names, retrieve the first or even all property name(s) which do(es) not exist at a given object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

I'm wondering if there is a way to find out which property name(s), out of a list of possible property names, do(es) not exist at an object. The code I came up with so far looks like that ...

```
let invalidBlocks = [];

blocks.map((block, index) => {
  if (!block.name || !block.formula || !block.id) {

    invalidBlocks.push(index + 1);
  }
});
```

Is there an elegant approach which finds the first or even all non existing property name(s) similar to the condition which got provided within the above code?

Comment: No, there's no built-in way to do that.

Comment: What do you want to do with that information? They may be an alternative way to achieve it that's "elegant"

Comment: @dantechguy I would like to include in an error message to user which parameter(s) need to be fixed

Comment: But `||` short-circuits, so you'd only find the first one, not all of them.

Comment: @Barmar good point, but even the first would be helpful in this case

Comment: @DLateef please check out my answer, maybe it will help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of all possible keys and the check based on that.

So, you can loop, over blocks, and then find the key which is not present over a particular block.

```js
const blocks = [{formula: 'exist', id: 'exist'}, {name: 'exist', id: 'exist'}, {name: 'exist', formula: 'exist'}, {name: 'exist', id: 'exist'}]

const invalidBlocks = blocks.map((block) => ['name', 'formula', 'id'].find((param) => !block[param]))

console.log(invalidBlocks)
```

This according to me is **elegant, and easy to understand**. There is no built-in way to check directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that filters a list of properties for those that don't exist on an object, and refactor your conditional statement to check for a non-empty list of missing properties:

```js
const findMissingProps = (props, obj) => props.filter(prop => !(prop in obj));

////// usage ////////

const blocks = [
  { name: "name", formula: "f", id: 1, },
  { formula: "f", id: 1, },
  { name: "name", formula: "f", },
  { name: "name" },
];

let invalidBlocks = [];
blocks.map((block, index) => {
  const missingProps = findMissingProps(["name", "formula", "id"], block);
  if (missingProps.length > 0) {
    console.error(`Block #${index} missing prop(s): ${missingProps.join(", ")}`);
    invalidBlocks.push(index + 1);
  }
});
```

Comment: This would definitely do the job well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this but I am not sure if this is what you wanted to achieve:

```
["name", "formula", "id"].forEach((item, index) => {
        if(!block[item]){
            invalidBlocks.push(index + 1)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. For me, hack would be to use array like this:

```
let invalidBlocks = []
blocks.map((block, index) => {
 const index = [!block.name, !block.formula, !block.id].findIndex(x => x) 
  if(index != -1) {
     invalidBlocks.push(index + 1)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the properties, and push the property names that have empty values into the array.

```js
let invalidBlocks = []

Object.entries(blocks).forEach([key, value] => {
  if (!value) {
    invalidBlocks.push(key)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#syntax) based approaches.

The 1st one returns for each *`blockList`* item a list of all omitted / missing (own) property names.

The 2nd approach slightly changes the implementation of the first one in order to return for each *`blockList`* item the first omitted / missing (own) property name.

Both approaches assume a *`keyList`* they can read from, provided as the `map` method's [`thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters_in_detail). Thus any callback function can operate at its `this` context.

For both approaches each `map`ping callback makes use of another callback, which checks whether a `key` (from the provided key list) can be accessed as the currently processed *`blockList`* item's [own property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

The difference is how one and the same callback gets used. The first approach operates it as [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#syntax) whereas the 2nd approach utilizes [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#syntax)

Here again, and for both approaches alike, the callback assumes the currently processed *`blockList`* item as its `this` context which `filter` and `find` both do provide.

```js
function isNotOwnPropertyOfBoundObject(key) {
  return !this.hasOwnProperty(key);
}

function getOmittedPropertiesFromBoundKeyList(item) {
  return this.filter(isNotOwnPropertyOfBoundObject, item);
}
function getFirstMissingPropertyFromBoundKeyList(item) {
  return this.find(isNotOwnPropertyOfBoundObject, item) || null;
}

const blockList = [
  { name: "name", formula: "f", id: 1 },
  { formula: "f", id: 1 },
  { name: "name", formula: "f" },
  { name: "name" },
];
const keyList = ["name", "formula", "id"];

console.log(
  'omitted property names for each block item ...',
  blockList.map(getOmittedPropertiesFromBoundKeyList, keyList)
);
console.log(
  'first missing property for each block item ...',
  blockList.map(getFirstMissingPropertyFromBoundKeyList, keyList)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @DLateef ... are there any questions regarding the above 2 approaches?

Comment: @DLateef ... and how about the implementations' briefness, cleanliness and elegance?